# Button to auto generate table entry

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to create a button with a macro assigned in excel that autogenerates a new entry with a UID automatically.

For example,

Current table

[image]

**User clicks button "New Entry"**

Updated table

[image]

Could this be done?
Current code can only add a new blank entry.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Select
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlUp
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, this can be done. What is the logic behind your UIDs and what have you tried so far?

Comment: @BigBen So far I am able to create a new entry but this code adds it to the top of the table..  Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Select ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlUp In regards to my logic I need "ID-CURRENTYEAR-001" but the new entry would increment by 1 by looking at the last 3 digits of the last entry.

Comment: Is this table an actual Excel table? ListObject in VBA speak.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Sure is.

Comment: @Daimen - i will post answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some slight hacks because it's late and I am tired, but this works. Change sheet and table name as needed.

```
Option Explicit

Sub fillNext()

Dim myTable As ListObject
Set myTable = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")

Dim myColumn As ListColumn
Set myColumn = myTable.ListColumns("UID")

With myColumn.DataBodyRange

    Dim order As String
    order = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1)
    order = Mid(order, InStr(InStr(order, "-") + 1, order, "-") + 1, 255)

    myTable.ListRows.Add

    .Cells(.Rows.Count + 1, 1).Value = "ID-YEAR-" & Format(CStr(CLng(order) + 1), "000")

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @ScottHoltman, How would I make the output "ID-UID-2020-"? I changed to add an extra "-" and it causes a run time error.